# How can we customize react-datepicker navigation buttons (--next and --previous )

Tags: javascript, react-datepicker

I am using reactDatePikcer and needs to change next and previous navigation with some other icons. Can't see any API to change next and previous buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS. For example to hide the arrow created with border properties and replace it your own css, text of icon font.

```
/* Hide current arrow */
.react-datepicker__navigation--previous {
   border-right-color: transparent;
} 
/* Display something else */
.react-datepicker__navigation--previous:after {
   content: 'XXX'
}
```

Comment: transparent hides but cant :after content is not replacing.
Seems like it should work but not replacing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [pickers from material-ui](https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/). They provide a hook to customize their components and also just make pickers look alot better in my opinion.

Comment: cant switch library :-)